# Loop a single Wordpress blog post in another page template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

is there a way to loop a post selected by ID in another post? I have a custom post type in wordpress, and want to get the title of another post selected by ID. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is. What you tried already?

Comment: Haven't tried anything at all, I searched for something similar but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Ok. Tell me more. Show example, how it should work etc.

Comment: I did it. All I did is start the first loop, than end it, start the second one with WP_Query, end it, and again start the first loop. It's working perfectly. Thanks anyway.